# Run and start denodo platform using Command Line Linux Remote Server without GUI

Tags: linux, windows, denodo

Run Denodo Platform sh files using Command Line Linux Remote Server. 
Denodo Platform showing GUI to start Virtual DataPort, and I can only interact using Command Line only.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh into the server and go to your DENODO_HOME\bin folder

run this command there:

```
sh vqlserver_startup.sh
```